# Connecting to Azure Blob Storage from Android

Tags: android, azure

I'm trying to make a mobile app that, eventually in one of its activities will connect to a Blob storage in Android to transfer a collection of images.

But I couldnt even get there, since one of the requirements is making that connection to be safe, since the client could be anyone from his mobile phone, so my first step here is requesting a SAS token prior to start any transaction.

So this is basically two steps that I'm following,

1 -> Implemented an Azure Function inside my App Service that returns a SAS token (I got that function from here: [Sas Token Function](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/functions-dotnet-sas-token)
)

2 -> Trying to call that function from my Android Code and get my SAS token.

Looks really easy and I'm sure it is, the function in the link explains  the required http body to ask for concrete access, and I think is there where I'm failing, below is my code to call the function:

```
private void getStringFromAzure() throws MalformedURLException {
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("container", "uploadedimages");
    jsonObject.addProperty("permissions", "Write, Create");
    // Create the MobileService Client object and set your backend URL
    String yourURL = "https://mydirectory.azurewebsites.net/";
    MobileServiceClient mClient = new MobileServiceClient(yourURL, this);

    // Your query pointing to yourURL/api/values
    ListenableFuture<JsonElement> query = mClient.invokeApi("GetSasToken-Net", jsonObject, "POST", null);

    // Callback method
    Futures.addCallback(query, new FutureCallback<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JsonElement jsonElement) {


            final String result = jsonElement.toString();

            // Since you are on a async task, you need to show the result on the UI thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + throwable.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

The code is failing in "InvokeApi" line function, where throws an exception before even warning me that is going to connect to Internet from mobile.

Another thing that I think could be wrong is that, nowhere in the Azure Get Sas Token Function is specifying my account credentials ( I didnt developed that function, but should work fine as it is, it anyways doesnt let you change anything, imported via GitHub )

I have really small base/background in this kind of things and Im sure I'm missing something (or "lots" of somethings), but I really appreciate a hand, this is driving me crazy.

PD. Internet permissions already given in manifest.

Thank you all in advance, first post in StackOverflow after following for many years!